# Event dependent on cell with formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new at VBA, which is why I'll ask a question here:

I have a report, which is set to change the right header font, size and content, all dependent on a cell value, and it is updated if I change the value of another cell. The problem is, the cell which value it is dependent on, stems from a formula, which is controlled by a timeline slicer.

The slicer determines the period of a certain pivot table, and the cell which changes takes the max date of this period (Cell is called 'EndDate'). From this, the cell which has the input to the header shows the current quarter (Cell is called 'ReportNo').

The code I have now is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("EndPeriod")) Is Nothing Then

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").PageSetup.RightHeader = "&28" & Me.Range("ReportNo").Text

    End If

End Sub
```

Is there any way, in which I can make the sheet run the VBA when the cell value changes in the formula dependent cell?

I've tried to add the first answer to the thread to the code: 
[image]

Comment: you could make use of the `worksheet.calculate` event. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-calculate-event-excel

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = Range("EndPeriod").Address Then 'if something changes on ReportNo
Call yourmacro 'call your vba macro
End If
End Sub

Sub yourmacro()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").PageSetup.RightHeader = "&28" & Me.Range("ReportNo").Text
End Sub
```

Add the code to:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure i understand where to put this code? Is it before or after the code I'm already using? And should I change the 'grey' text in your code to something else, if so, then what? :-)

Comment: The grey text are comments to help you understand the code, the code should be added on the Worksheet that contains the range ReportNo... So you could replace your code with my answer...

Comment: I've added an image to illustrate where the code ought to go... hope this makes it clear, you should make sure that at the top you have selected "Worksheet" and to its right you should select "Change" then add the code there and you can have yourmacro code below it, or even in a module...

Comment: I'm still not sure i understand. Below I've tried to add a picture of what I've done. I entered my code after your code. Maybe you could try to combine the two codes, so I know how exactly to put it in?

Comment: Just replace your code with mine and every time anything changes on ReportNo the yourmacro should run, you can then edit the macro to do whatever you wanted it to do instead of a simple msgbox..

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("ReportNo").Address Then
        Call yourmacro
    End If
End Sub

Sub yourmacro()
      If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("EndPeriod")) Is Nothing Then
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").PageSetup.RightHeader = "&28" & Me.Range("ReportNo").Text
      End If
End Sub

Comment: That did not look very clear, but i tried to replace the msgbox with my own code, and it does still not run the code when the cell changes :-(

Comment: Do me a favor and add a link to your workbook by uploading it to something like Dropbox or Google Drive and then add the link to a comment, I will look into it and then send it back?

Comment: Unfortunately no, most of the data on the file is confidential. I tried to copy all of the code you wrote, but it does not execute when the value in EndPeriod, which is dependent on the slicer, changes. The value only changes when i 'type' in the cell ReportNo, without changing anything in the cell.

Comment: The code I included runs when the value of ReportNo changes... if you want it to run when EndPeriod changes then you need to alter the code slightly...

Comment: I've now updated my answer so that when the value of EndPeriod changes then your code should run,...

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem in another way, but thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @user8863469 please could you mark my response as an answer if it has helped you? Thanks.